# Qt doesn't play sound on other devices

Tags: c++, qt, audio, qtmultimedia, qmediaplayer

All I want to do write a programm in Qt that plays a simple .wav file.
This works perfectly on the PC where my Qt runs, but whenever I want to run the program on a different computer there is no sound.
I couldn't find any solution for this problem anywhere yet.

This is what I tried so far:

- different libraries: QSound, QSoundEffect, QMediaPlayer
- implement the QT += multimedia in the .pro file (of course)
- make sure that the filepath was correct (even with a absolute path):

`QFile dir("C:/Sounds/countdown3.wav");
        if(dir.exists()){
            ui->labelSound->setText("File found!");
            ui->pushButtonPlay->setEnabled(true);
            ui->labelplay->setEnabled(true);
            ui->pushButton->setEnabled(false);
        }
        else ui->labelSound->setText("File not available!");`

(When I rename the file I get the "File not available!" message, so this works.)

To deploy the program from my pc to my laptop, I put the following into a folder:

- PlaySound.exe
- platforms/qwindows.dll
- icudt53.dll
- icuin53.dll
- icuuc53.dll
- libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll
- libstdc++-6.dll
- libwinpthread-1.dll
- Qt5Core.dll
- Qt5Gui.dll
- Qt5Multimedia.dll
- Qt5Network.dll
- Qt5Widgets.dll

and the "Sounds" folder with countdown3.wav to the C:/ -drive. Still no sound :(

What am I missing?

I hope you can help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The audio plugins folder: `[Qt-Installation]\5.4\msvc2013\plugins\audio`

1. `audio\qtaudio_windows.dll` what you need
2. `audio\qtaudio_windowsd.dll` is the debug library
3. `audio\qtaudio_windowsd.pdb` symbols

You don't need to deploy the last two.

Comment: Had to put it into an additional audio folder but then it worked!

Thank you very much, dear sir! :D

Comment: Right, all plugins go into a subfolder, just like `platforms`.